# Elastic search script_exception: scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 2.3.1 and when i am trying to Sorting on Fields Containing Numbers it is showing the error Elastic search script_exception: scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled.
I have added script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on  in my elasticsearch.yml but still i am getting error.

Comment: Please consult this link and you'll see what you need to add to your config: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Answer (score 0):

The ElasticSearch Update API has changed a number of times and many answers you see are related to different ES versions. When searching the ES docs ensure you are looking at the docs related to your version of ES.

In your elasticsearch.yml:

`script.inline: true
script.indexed: true`